# Path associated to Views

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases

I used Pathauto to create URLs for my nodes like `gallery/[node:title]`.

I created a view with an argument, and the path is `gallery/%` (`%` is the node title), but when I point my browser to that URL, I get the standard node, not the view.

How can I override the paths to get my view on that path?
How can I increase the weight of views.module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the weight of views.module, you can execute the following code:

```
db_update('system')
  ->fields(array('weight' => 10))
  ->condition('name', 'views')
  ->execute();
```

Comment: I made a mistake when I wrote the post :) the problem is still there, I need to override those and give more weight to the views so drupal will render my view instead of a normal page.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best option here is to actually let Panels take care of this. Install panels, create a variant of the node view panel for the specific node type(s) you want, and then place the view on the panel page. There are a few other options (hook_menu_alter(), using hook_url_alter() to rewrite the node links rather than using pathauto), but I would definitely go the panels route.